# How to remove objects from an array by variable value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm coding a Pokemon generator and trying to make an option to exclude certain types from the results.

I've "tried" splice and filter functions but my understanding is pretty limited so I may have just been using them wrong.

I've got this variable full of objects like

```
var pokemonChoices = [{
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    type: ["Grass","Poison"]
  }, {
    name: 'Charmander',
    type: ["Fire"]
  }];
```

Then I've got a dropdown menu with types and a variable called excludetype that gets its value from it.

How do I make it so I can create a new array excluding, for instance, all Pokemon with the type "Grass", or whatever excludetype is set to?

================================

EDIT: I think I've got it working using

```
  var Excludinator = pokemonChoices.filter(function( obj ) { return obj.type.includes(excludetype); }); 

  pokemonChoices = pokemonChoices.filter(function(item) {
  return !Excludinator.includes(item); 
  })
```

Comment: Your input looks malformed - are you really using the comma operator, or did you mean to surround the objects in an `[]` array?

Comment: The posted code is not valid JavaScript

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yes I meant to wrap it in [], edited now. I promise it's correct in the code and everything else works except the desired filtering. I just spaced when writing the example here.

Comment: So basically what I gave in my answer

Answer (score 1):

To get all Pokemon with the `type` containing `grass`, you can use `filter` with `includes`:

```js
const pokemonChoices = [{name:'Bulbasaur',type:["Grass","Poison"]},{name:'Charmander',type:["Fire"]}];

const pokemonByType = t => pokemonChoices.filter(({ type }) => type.includes(t));

console.log(pokemonByType("Grass"));
console.log(pokemonByType("Fire"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
// Array holding your Pokemon Objects
const pokemonChoices = [
  {
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    type: ['Grass', 'Poison'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Charmander',
    type: ['Fire'],
  },
];

// Function where you pass in the excluded type and it filters out Pokemon that include it.
const searchPokemon = exclude => {
  return pokemonChoices.filter(pokemon => !pokemon.type.includes(exclude));
};

console.log(searchPokemon('Poison'));
```

You can find more info on [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) at these links.